# How can I remove the simulators from my build targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

In Xcode, I have a project that uses a library only built for the device.

I now run into the issue whenever I disconnect my phone and reconnect it, Xcode wants to build for a simulator, which I don't want.

Is there a way to exclude the simulators from the build targets list?

Answer (score 0):

It's not project specific but from the 'Devices' window you can remove a simulator from the run destinations list. Simply right click on one and you'll see

[image: Devices context menu screenshot]

You'll have to do it to all of your installed simulators, but you can remove  them.